# Control the Topic level permission in Confluent Cloud through Control Center

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud, confluent-control-center

I'm not able to find Option to control the Topic level permission in Cloud Based Free Trial of Confluent Platform. Can you please suggest on how to configure ?

Answer (score 0):

Confluent Cloud role-based access control (RBAC) provides a method to control access to an organization, environment, or cluster configuration using predefined roles. RBAC enables enterprises to protect their production environment by isolating user and service account access and allowing for the delegation of authorization to the appropriate business units and teams.

To control access to specific resources within a cluster, such as Kafka topics or ksqlDB applications, continue to use ACLs.

RBAC does not provide granular support for Kafka resources (like topics), nor does it provide granular access control for individual connectors, ksqlDB applications, and schema subjects.

ACL are not manged by the Control Center

https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/access-management/cloud-rbac.htm

ACLs are managed using the Confluent Cloud CLI. For a complete list of Kafka ACLs, see Authorization using ACLs.

https://docs.confluent.io/ccloud-cli/current/command-reference/kafka/acl/index.html#ccloud-kafka-acl

```
 ccloud kafka acl create --allow --service-account sa-55555 --operation READ --operation DESCRIBE --consumer-group java_example_group_1
 ccloud kafka acl create --allow --service-account sa-55555 --operation READ --operation DESCRIBE --topic '*'
```